# How to make loader only run when page assets load the first time - but not after they get cached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to run a loader only when someone visits a web page for the first time and not have the loader run again after the web page is cached.

Is there a way to make sure a loader only runs when the assets on a page/window are loaded for the first time, but not after the assets get cached.

HTML

```
   <div id="preloader">
       <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(window).on("load", function (e) {
            if($('#preloader').length > 0){
                $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE:**
Using HTML localstorage seems to work well.

```
     $(window).on("load", function (e) {
            localStorage.loaded = "yes";
            if($('#preloader').length > 0){
                $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
            }
        });

    if (localStorage.loaded == "yes") {
            $('#preloader').remove();
            //or any other method of not showing the spinner
        }
```

Comment: set a cookie on initial visit, then run a conditional to check if the cookie exists and run your function based on the result

Comment: so it can only be done with like backend php..?

Comment: you can set cookies with js doesnt need to be server side, the cookie is stored clientside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,this worked for me,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var check=getCookie("loader");

    if (check!="false") {
            var loader="true";
    }else{
        loader=check;
    };
    if (loader=="true") {

    document.cookie="loader=false";
      loader=getCookie("loader");
    //your function

    }else {
        //alert(check);
        //alert(loader);
    //your function;
    }
    });

    function getCookie(name) {
      return (name = (document.cookie + ';').match(new RegExp(name + '=.*;'))) && name[0].split(/=|;/)[1];
    }
```